# synchronizing progress database with sql Server database

Tags: sql-server, openedge, progress-db

Please I need to synchronize two databases one in Progress OpenEdge and the other is in SQL Server so that I have the same data in both databases.

Do you have any idea if it is possible? If so: how can we do this?

Comment: Never heard or "Progress", do you mean "postgresql"? Are you a programmer? If so, what language? Or are you asking for software suggestions, which is against the rules of this web site?

Comment: Progress is a full language / application platform - see progress.com for the company site. Do you want to synchronize the DB once, or as an ongoing process?

Comment: I need to synchronize both DB (SQL Server and Progress OpenEdge)  each 5 min for exemple

Answer (score 0):

For live replication Progress Software offers something called "OpenEdge Pro 2" - a software for replicating an OpenEdge database into SQL Server. See link below.

For a one off there are multiple ways of dumping data in different formats. How to do this depends very much on your capabilities, the structure of the database etc.

https://www.progress.com/openedge/features/openedge-pro2